# Filemaker summarize related field if

Tags: filemaker, portal, summary

I have a FM13 DB with a table "machines" and its related table "consumption" connected with the IDs.
My layout is showing the machines data and a portal with the related consumption entries.
Now I want to summarize the fields "amount" of all related entries where "fuelType" is "diesel" and the "year" is "2015" into one calculted field within the machines table.

Can anyone give me a clue how to do that?

thx
dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the ways Michael suggested, FM13 introduced the [ExecuteSQL](http://www.filemaker.com/help/12/fmp/html/func_ref3.33.6.html) command, which can used in a calculated field. The calculation would look something like this:

```
ExecuteSQL (
    "SELECT SUM(amount)" & ¶ &
    "FROM consumption" & ¶ &
    "WHERE FuelType = 'diesel' AND \"Year\" = 2015" ;
    "" ; ""
)
```

Comment: thank to all of you guys! I managed to solved it. I created a script that switches to the consumptions layout and searched for the criteria mentioned and summarizes the amounts. Probably the FM-newbee way. I'll definitely check the SQL-commands for future calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Create another relationship based on a calculation field in both tables based on concatenate fields:

id_fueltype_year: 12345_diesel_2015

You can then create a Calculation field in Machines containing Sum(newrelation: amount)

If you hard code the fueltype in the calc field machines table, then the result will always be the specified fuel type (e.g. diesel). Thus you would need to create multiple fields for each field type. Or you could create a fuel type field and as you change it the summary calc field would update upon selection.

Comment: You know we had multi-predicate relationships since v.7?

Answer (score 1):

If this is for display only, you could simply create a one-row portal based on the existing relationship and filter it to show only records where =

```
Consumption::FuelType = "diesel" and Consumption::Year = 2015
```

or (preferably, IMHO) =

```
Consumption::FuelType = Machines::gFuelType 
and 
Consumption::Year = Machines::gYear
```

with `Machines::gFuelType` and `Machines::gYear` being global fields where you can select any type/year to summarize.

Place a summary field defined (in the Consumption table) as Total of [Amount] inside the filtered portal.

If you need the result as data for further processing, then you will need to add a dedicated relationship (using another occurrence of the Consumption table) as:

```
Machines::MachineID = Consumption 2::MachineID
AND
Machines::gFuelType = Consumption 2::FuelType
AND
Machines::gYear = Consumption 2::Year
```

and use `Sum ( Consumption 2::Amount )` to summarize the relevant entries.